# Запись id просмотренных страниц в Cookie (PHP)

Tags: php, cookie

Как можно записать id просмотренных страниц в куки?
И при следующих запросах, исключать их. Что бы при повторном посещении сайта, пользователю не показывались те же статьи, которые он уже смотрел при нажатии на кнопку Next.

У меня записывается только одна запись.

Comment: пишите в массив и сериализуйте его

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer unserialize?

Comment: да, serialize и unserialize

Comment: Только не забывайте, что хранилище под куки не бесконечное и они передаются на сервер при каждом запросе, соответственно в вашем случае сайт будет все медленнее и медленнее грузится

Comment: @korytoff а как сделать, чтобы не навредить времени загрузки? 
Можно ли сделать временные куки, к примеру на час? А далее удалять.

Comment: Да, во первых можно, а во вторых для этого есть сессии. Почитайте в документации

Comment: Как пользователь сможет вернуться к просмотренной статье, если захочет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id статей – числа? Скорее всего, 32-битные, не больше – т.е. 4 байта. Я бы предложил их запаковывать [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pack.php) в 4-байтовые бинарные строки и записывать в куки через [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-encode.php) – это может дать некоторый выигрышь в объёме хранимых в куки данных, когда статей много и id длинные.

Наскоро набросал, не проверял подробно. Если запрашивать с `?id=12345` - id будет запоминаться в куки вместе с предыдущими. Просмотренные id – в массиве `$seen`:

```
<?php
define('COOK_NAME', 'seen');
define('COOK_TTL', 3600);

$seen = array();
if( isset($_COOKIE[ COOK_NAME])) {
    $bin = base64_decode($_COOKIE[ COOK_NAME]);
    if( FALSE !== $bin  &&  strlen($bin) > 0  &&  strlen($bin)%4 === 0) {
        $seen = array_map( 'fromFourBytes', str_split($bin,4));
    } else {
        echo "Unpack failed";
    }
}

function fromFourBytes($str) {
    $arr = unpack('Vid', $str);
    return $arr['id'];
}

function toFourBytes($id) {
    return pack('V', $id);
}

if( isset($_GET['id'])  &&  ($id = intval($_GET['id']))) {
    if( !in_array($id, $seen)) array_push( $seen, $id);

    $value = base64_encode( implode('', array_map('toFourBytes', $seen)));
    setcookie( COOK_NAME, $value, time() + COOK_TTL);   
}


echo "<p>Seen: " . implode(',', $seen) . "</p>";
echo "<p>Raw cookie: " . $_COOKIE[ COOK_NAME] . "</p>";
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо! Но как мне исключить просмотренные id из запроса?
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM fakt WHERE id!='Что нужно вписать сюда?'") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: `..WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(',',$seen) . ")` – получится `..NOT IN (1,23,456)`. Поскольку распаковывается через `V` это относительно безопасно, но можно сделать «правильнее».

Answer (score 1):

Я так реализовал последние просмотренные записи, можете отталкиваться от этого

```
$getid = intval($_GET['id']);
$dt = time();
if (isset($_COOKIE['viewed'])) {
    $viewed = urldecode($_COOKIE['viewed']);
    if (stristr($viewed, $getid.',') == true) {
        $viewed = preg_replace('/'.$getid.',/','',$viewed);
        $viewed = $getid.','.$viewed;
        setcookie ('viewed', $viewed, $dt+864000, '/', SITE);
    } else {
        $viewed = $getid.','.$viewed;
        setcookie ('viewed', $viewed, $dt+864000, '/', SITE);
    }
} else {
    setcookie ('viewed', $getid.',', $dt+864000, '/', SITE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем держать это в куки? Пишите в базу по конкретному пользователю, оттуда же считываете и выдаете в списке новостей только не прочитанные. куки ж не вечные - теряется смысл...

Comment: Зачем: 1. анонимусы; 2. хранение в куках «бесплатно» для сайта.

Comment: ну да, если аноним то косяк, но тогда вопрос зачем для анонима временно скрывать записи? Все скорее всего зависит от конкретных условий проета...

Comment: напр. анекдоты )

Comment: такой вариант не продумал) + в карму)